# Probability of intersection of non increasing sequence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $(C_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is a sequence of events such that $C_{n+1} \subset C_n$ for every $n\geqslant1$. Then how to prove the following probability statement?  $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(C_n) = P\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n \right).$$

I know how to prove the following:

Suppose that $(C_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is a sequence of events such that $C_n \subset C_{n+1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$. Then we have $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(C_n) = P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n \right).$$

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't $C_1$ a 1-event sequence?

Comment: @SDiv Happy now?

Comment: No, it turns out I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Some information can be found here: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~aey/eecs501/lectures/cond.pdf
This can be used in conjunction with Liu Gang's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $C_{n+1} \subset C_{n}$, then $C_{n}^c \subset C_{n+1}^c$. Thus we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}  P(C_n^c) = P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty C_n^c)$, by what you know how to prove.

Since $P(C_n^c) = 1 - P(C_n)$ and $P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty C_n^c) = P((\cap_{n=1}^\infty C_n)^c) = 1 - P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty C_n)$, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(C_n) = P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty C_n)$

Comment: Since $C_{n+1} \subset C_n$, so $P(C_{n+1} \cap C_n) = P(C_n|C_{n+1})P(C_{n+1}) = P(C_{n+1})$, it's tempting to take the limit for $P(\cap_{n} C_n)=P(C_n)$. Why is it wrong?