# Proving probability of intersection of union equals zero

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $C_1, C_2, \ldots $ be a sequence of events in a probability space
>   $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(C_n) = 0$
>   and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(C_{n + 1} \setminus C_{n}) < \infty$. Prove
>   that
>
> $$P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} C_{k}\right) =
>  0.$$

I'm stuck on this problem for a pretty long time. I've seen the following example, which is similar: [Probability of intersection of non increasing sequence of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888849/probability-of-intersection-of-non-increasing-sequence-of-events)

But it is not enough to help me solve the problem. It seems like there are so many details that I am given, and I am not sure how to use them all.

I would appreciate some sort of help as I have been stuck on this problem for many days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by measure continuity from above,
$$
P(\cap_{n=1}^ {\infty}\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k).
$$
Moreover, countable additivity yields that
\begin{align}
P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k)
&=[P(A_n)+ P(A_{n+1}\cap A_n^c)+P(A_{n+2}\cap A_{n+1}^c\cap A_n^c)+\dotsb]\\
&\leq P(A_n)+\sum_{k=n}^\infty P(A_{k+1}\setminus A_{k})\to 0
\end{align}
as $n\to \infty$ where in the last line we use the hypotheses of the problem. The result follows.